# Docker does not map nest module and NestJs returns 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs, backend

I am new to NestJs and currently trying to create a new NestJS module + its controller. But I'm getting a 404 error whenever I try to test or access the API route(using POSTMAN). Docker does not Map the modules/controllers that i create. The other modules, as you will see below, work fine, but the on i created ( called Ecologi) does not work.

PS: The project runs in docker. I noticed that Docker also doesn't map the modules, but i dont know any fix to that

This is the error that i am getting:

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "Cannot GET /api/ecologi",
    "error": "Not Found"
}
```

This is how my app.module.ts file looks like:

```
import { ConversationModule } from './conversation/conversation.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as path from 'path';
import { AdvertiseModule } from './advertise/advertise.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { EventModule } from './events/event.module';
import { SchoolModule } from './school/school.module';
import { DonationModule } from './donation/donation.module';
import { ProductModule } from './product/product.module';
import { NotificationService } from 'src/utils/services/notification.service';
import { OrderModule } from './order/order.module';
import { ContactUsModule } from './contactUs/contactUs.module';
import { NewsFeedModule } from './news-feed/news-feed.module';
import { EcologiModule } from './ecologi/ecologi.module';
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;

@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            envFilePath: [path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'env/.env'), path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'env', !NODE_ENV ? '.dev.env' : `.${NODE_ENV}.env`)],
            isGlobal: true,
        }),
        AdvertiseModule,
        AuthModule,
        EventModule,
        SchoolModule,
        DonationModule,
        ProductModule,
        OrderModule,
        ContactUsModule,
        NewsFeedModule,
        ConversationModule,
        EcologiModule
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [NotificationService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is how the module (ecologi.module.ts) who's routes and controller i want to access looks like:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EcologiController } from './ecologi.controller';
import { EcologiService } from './ecologi.service';

@Module({
  controllers: [EcologiController],
  providers: [EcologiService]
})
export class EcologiModule {}
```

The controller (ecologi.controller.ts) :

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('ecologi')
export class EcologiController {
    @Get()
    test(){
        return 'tesing api'
    }
}
```

main.ts:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './modules/app.module';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { useContainer } from 'class-validator';
import { join } from 'path';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
    const port = +app.get(ConfigService).get('PORT') || 4000;

    /** Static files serving */
    app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '/../../public'));


    /** Container for custom validation in dto */
    useContainer(app.select(AppModule), { fallbackOnErrors: true });

    /** Enable cors */
    app.enableCors();

    /**Global path prefix */
    app.setGlobalPrefix('api');

    await app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server listening on port >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>:  ${port}  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<`);
    });
}
bootstrap();
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine

# create destination directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/api
WORKDIR /usr/src/api

# update and install dependency
RUN apk update && apk upgrade

# copy the app, note .dockerignore
COPY . /usr/src/api/

RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start:dev" ]
```

Comment: What request path do you use? Can you provide a request/response?